# Throwing out a non-distinct ball while also picking a ball without replacement

Tags: probability

Let's say I have $N$ balls, of which $k$ are red and the rest are blue. The probability that I pick all the red balls without replacement in $n$ attempts is:

$\frac{\binom{k}{k}*\binom{N-k}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}$
right?  *But* what if I peek into the bag and discard one blue ball after each random draw, regardless of what was chosen?

What would the probability be then?

Comment: Discard a blue no matter which ball is selected?

Comment: Yes, discard a blue regardless

Comment: You first probability should be $\binom{k}n\binom{N-k}0\big/\binom{N}n$.

Comment: A clearer statement of the procedure proposed in the body of your Question would improve it.  While the title includes the phrase "with replacement" (as also the phrase "non-distinct ball"), it invites confusion to have critical information that appears only in the title and not in the body.  In particular it is unclear from what collection you intend to "discard one blue ball after each random draw."

Comment: "without replacement" sorry! ugh very unfortunate typo.

Comment: The rules aren't clear.  If we draw a blue ball, do we discard two blue balls or just the one we drew?  What if there are no more blue balls?

Comment: Yes, discard a blue ball, even if a blue ball was drawn at random - in this case two are removed. If no more blue balls, then end.